# c++ call asm in line

Tags: c++, assembly

I am not sure if I am doing right to call a method from asm for a c++ method.

c++ hkDrawIndexdPrimitive method:

```
HRESULT WINAPI hkDrawIndexedPrimitive (LPDIRECT3DDEVICE8 pDevice,
D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimType, UINT minIndex, UNIT NumVertices, UNIT startIndex, UINT primCount)
```

asm code to call hkDrawIndexdPrimitive method:

```
__declspec(naked) void DIP_Mid( ) {
 __asm {
     pushad
     pushfd

     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x1C]            // primCount               [4 Bytes]
     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x18]            // startIndex              [4 Bytes]
     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x14]            // NumVertices             [4 Bytes]
     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x10]            // minIndex                [4 Bytes]
     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x0C]            // PrimType                [4 Bytes]
     PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x08]            // pDevice                 [4 Bytes]

     CALL hkDrawIndexedPrimitive

     popad
     popfd

     XOR ESI,ESI                              // Replace Code 0x6D9D73D1 [2 Bytes]
     CMP DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+18],EBX            // Replace Code 0x6D9D73D3 [3 Bytes]

     JMP dwDIPRet;                            // Return to 0x6D9D73D6
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading from `0x00000018` (`xor esi, esi; cmp [esi+18h], ...`)?

Comment: insert this "__declspec(naked) void DIP_Mid" into 0x6D6D73D1. and this "__declspec(naked) void DIP_Mid" takes 5 bytes. 0X6D6D73D1 and 0x6d9D73D3 = 5 bytes. in my inline asm, i replace the code and return to 0x6D9D73D6.

Comment: am my question is hard to understand?

Comment: @lannyboy - Yes, it's too hard. We wonder about "what" and "why". What are you trying to do? And why doing it the most difficult way possible? I know easier ways to call a C function from a C or C++ program.

Comment: I just tried deassembled from OllyDbg and read from the functions and my code is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Your `popad` and `pushfd` do not match the `pushad` and `pushfd`. Also you are throwing away the return value. It sounds like you're trying to cheat at a video game.

Comment: Raymond: Yea, you're right. I am coding to bypassing the anti-cheat game program. Well, even I fixed the order of the PUSHFD & PUSHAD and POPFD & POPAD, I still got the crash... Code was able to call void hkDrawIndexedPrimitive function. But it can't return to POPFD and POPAD lines. It just straight away threw me out from the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing it the hard way? D3D uses COM, which has virtual function tables for all the object methods, meaning you don't need to delve into assembly depths and rely on system/compiler dependent inline ASM. It also has the added benefit of being object local, instead of application or system local.

There are also libraries to make this sort of thing easier, such as [MS Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), [here](http://s1.zetaboards.com/hLibrary/topic/748957/1/) is a nice tutorial on using detours for hooking a D3D9 object, the exact same would apply for D3D8 (only that might change is VFT offsets.

In terms of your assembly being correct, it seems you assume there is a stack frame already setup, but AFAIK, COM doesn't use stack frames, so EBP might not point to the top of the stack. also, you need to pair push and pop instructions, as the stack is FILO, first in, last out, eg: in your case, you should have

```
PUSHFD
PUSHAD
//code...
POPAD
POPFD
```

Else you'll pop random garbage back into EFLAGS and the other registers

Comment: yea, thanks. i fixed the order in which a way called FILO but then i still have the crash. detour doesn't work for my game as it has anti-cheat game program protection. the only hard way can solve to bypass the anti-cheat game program...